# Streamlit logout should switch to entry point page

Tags: streamlit

I am working on streamlit multipage app and I have created a folder pages and inside pages I have stored my other python scripts. My entry point file is login.py which is basically to authenticate users credentials. Once the credentials are verified it displays the 1_page.py inside pages. I added logout button in 1_page.py. The rationale is once the logout button is clicked it has to go back to entry point page which is login.py. I tried switch_page but it doesn’t seem to find the file. Is there any hack to get around with it?

I would like the switch_page command to work as it shows that the login.py is not available.

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible code?